# Get back space button click action event in Autocomplete text view

Tags: java, android, textview, autocompletetextview

I am using autocomplete text view in my app.But my requirement is When i am editing some letters in autocomplete text view by pressing back space button, i want to do some action at that time.I am using below code but its not working.

```
actv.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            //You can identify which key pressed buy checking keyCode     value with KeyEvent.KEYCODE_
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                new RestaurantTask().execute("http://xxxx.co.in/xxxx_project/index.php/api/user/get_list/format/json",customerIdOnly);

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using textwatcher as follows.
Hope it helps. thanks

```
actv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // perform your tasks here like
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                 
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```